# Copy and mutiple insert into (mysql)?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, cascade, lastinsertid

My problem is very simple to explain but I don't success to find the right answer to it !

I have 3 tables in mysql, called tA, tB, tC. I have one entry A in tA, 2 entries B in tB and 3 entries C in tC with a hierarchical architecture like this:

```
            A
            |
     ----------------
     |              |
     B1             B2
     |              |
 --------           |
 |      |           |
 C1     C2          C3
```

As you can imagine, I have B entries are linked to A entries with A id, and C entries are linked to B entries with B id.

I just want to copy these data to :

```
            A'
            |
     ----------------
     |              |
     B1'            B2'
     |              |
 --------           |
 |      |           |
 C1'    C2'         C3'
```

So at the beginning, I start by creating A' and copying the B entries linked to A'. No worries.

But after, I did a request with a left join to copy C entries to C'. It nearly works... the only problem is that, by this way, my C' entries are linked to B id and not to B' id !!!!

I try some other stuffs but I don't know how to do that. It seems so simple. Maybe I'm tired... Maybe I have to copy B entries one by one, and copy all C entries of the current B entry before to go to the next.

But is there not a smarter way to do that ? With insert_id, cascade, trigger, foreign key ???

I'm not a sql specialist and I hope somebody here will have a nice solution.

Thanks by advance.

Bastien

Comment: I can't really think of a pure sql way to do this, but could easily handle it with php or coldfusion. Are you using any sort of application to access your db? if so, what language and I'll try to help you out there.

Comment: My app is based on CodeIgniter (php). I basically use ActiveRecord but sometimes for complex requests, I directly use query with native sql. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alain's method is a possible way to handle this purely in SQL, but requires some table modifications, basically storing the original id that an object was copied from.

So you said you are using php, and I wish I could give you more relevant examples, but I've been away from php too long. But you should be able to do the following.

1. Get A from the database, store A id in a variable in php (suggest $oldAID)
2. Copy A properties and store back to the db as A'
3. Get Last Insert ID and store as variable (suggest $newAID)
4. Get all B records from DB where parent = $oldAID
5. Loop through the b records, store the current records id as $oldBID
6. Copy B1 propertied and store back to DB as B1' with a parent id $newAID
7. Get last insertID ans store as $newBID
8. Get all C records from DB where parent ID = $oldBID
9. Make Copies and store back to DB with parent ID = $newBID
10. Itterate through your loop started in step 5

By using PHP to keep tabs on your last insert ID's you can make the copies you need and keep them accurate. Downside to this, there is a lot of back and forth between php and MySQL so in a really large set, that would go several levels deep, a process like this can take a few seconds. But if your normal sets are as small and shallow as your example, it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: Thanks. That's the solution I found and wrote in my question. So, I think I will keep it. Seems to be the only one. What I thought, by posting the question on SO, was that there could have been a solution like a ON DELETE CASCADE but for insert. It seems not ! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to your second set of tables that would contain the ID from the original set.  After you've created A', you can use the original IDs to create the B' entries.  Then, use the original IDs from B' to create C'.

Make sense?

So, with more info from @bastien, I would suggest adding a column to tableA called something like `old_id`.  When you insert your copied rows, put the original `id` into `old_id`.  You can then use `old_id` to find the related rows in tableB, tableC, etc.

Comment: The tables are the same. Just the entries are copied. I explain: at the end, you A and A' in tA, B1, B2, B1' and B2' in tB and C1, C2, C3, C1', C2', C3' in tC. And the copy is a temporary command. Don't need to keep that A' is a copy of A. So adding a column which is used only for copy in each table seems to me a bit hardcoded. I will think about it... But thanks for the answer

Comment: The point was that you need some way to access both the `A` and `A'` values when working with the later tables.  The extra column gives you that ability.  There are probably other ways, too.  Good luck.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "later tables". There is not a second set of tables. There is only one set with the tables tA, tB and tC. Can you explain this point ?

Comment: To insert into `B'` (a table that you insert "later" than `A'`), you need to ID from `A` and `A'`.

Comment: But B' is not a table ! B' is an entry, like A' and C'. Entries are : A, B1, B2, C1, C2, C3 and also A', B1', B2', C1', C2', C3'. Tables are only tA, tB and tC. So the entries B1' and B2' are in the table tB. That's why I don't understand what you are talking about and where I have to add the column.

Comment: You drew a hierarchy of tables (A-C) then said you wanted to copy info to another hierarchy (A'-C').  I guess I must have just assumed those were tables.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and your time Alain. I understand now (maybe my wording and schemes were not clear enough) and agree it will do the job. But for my needs, I used already the answer above (the one I wrote in my question with a simple loop). It works great and no need to alterate the DB.